# Put column text in tooltip if its too long in angular view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have in my htm page a table with columns using AngularJs.

I want to put the text in tooltip if the text in column is more than 8 characters

this is my column :

```
<td>
<i class="column3">
    {{stoneEntity.StoneProperties.StockId}}
</i>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a directive like this:

```
app.directive('showTooltip', function() {
    var MAX_SIZE = 8;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { label: '=showTooltip' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                        
            if ((scope.label || '').length > MAX_SIZE) {                
                element.text(scope.label.substring(0, MAX_SIZE));
                element.attr('title', scope.label);                
            } else {
                element.text(scope.label);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note: For the sake of simplicity, the `MAX_SIZE` is being defined inside the directive but you can change it and receive the max size as a parameter.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/h5Np6/

Comment: this example looks perfect but it soesnt work for me. I tried exactly the same cut in html :  <p show-tooltip="stoneEntity.StoneProperties.StockId"></p>

Comment: Are you importing the directive into the application? Try to debug the application and check if it enters the `link` function inside the directive. Also a fiddle or a code snippet would be great.

Comment: Now it works!I put into <p> like you instead of <div> ! it must be into <p>?

Comment: @BrMe There shouldn't be any problem using `<div>` instead of `<p>`. You can test that on the fiddle I've provided and it will work.